# opacity problem in Ie 8 with jquery

Tags: jquery

here is my jquery code

```
$("span.stage").hover(
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
$(".stagehover").css("display","block").fadeIn(-10);
},
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
$(".stagehover").css("display","none").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

It works fine in frirfox but it shows black border in IE onmousover. I'm using .png image file.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the element you are trying to adjust the opacity for "have layout".

http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

You can also try to set these two properties:
-moz-opacity: 0.70; 
filter: alpha(opacity=70);